# Make a simple HTML5 page as an standalone exe

Tags: html, windows, browser, exe

Basically I'm doing a simple form snippet in HTML with jQuery. The problem is that it's going to be opened in computers with no (proper) browser installed. I figured out that, instead of asking to install Chrome/Firefox/Whatever, package the whole page inside a 32-bit executable, How can i do that?